# XCode error "The application bundle does not contain a valid identifier."

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

Recently, after upgrading to Lion and Xcode 4.2.1 I am getting this error when trying to run my app on my iPhone 4S:

"The application bundle does not contain a valid identifier."

My identifier is indeed valid, and I have been able to run my app with this identifier earlier.

The problem might appear when I change computers.
I have two computers that I am using to code my app, and I am using Dropbox to keep track of my files.

Restarting XCode, my mac and my iPhone does not work.
Cleaning the target and rebuilding does not work.
The only thing I have been able to do to fix it is to create a completely new project and moving my files. This made things work until I swapped computer. Now I am in the same trouble again.

Any idea? Anyone?

Answer (score 3):

Three suggestions:

1. Check that your developer key is in both computers
2. Did you try to update the project? There is a strangly-named key in the middle bottom under the project's properties. Try this.
3. I had similar issues. I found that some things weren't updated when I updated osx and xcode. To get out of the situation, I would suggest creating a new project and copy paste code, files and build settings. This might seem stupid, but you know apple is not good at creating IDE's. You might just get your self lost in the undocumented settings.